# Laravel Passport works with PostMan but not APP?

Tags: reactjs, laravel, axios, laravel-passport

I have a route that needs a token. When I make my Axios call inside of the react app, it returns `401`. However, when I grab the parsed header inside of the Network tab it shows:

```
Bearer ${correctToken}
```

I grab that entire string, `Bearer ${token}` and throw it into `PostMan` and I get the correct object, no `401`.

I have tried all the fixes and am now on page 3 of google, the dark abyss.

**Any idea how to fix this?**